# Migrando código a net.core 5

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-5.0

Estoy intentando migrar mi clases realizadas en MVC a NET.core 5 y tengo el siguiente problema al momento de utilizar `HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath` y el `Configuration.GetConnectionString`.

El mensaje que me devuelve al utilizar estas líneas es el siguiente: **El nombre 'HttpContext' | 'Configuration'  no existe en el contexto actual**

He venido leyendo documentación pero no logro refactorizar para reescribir mi código en está nueva versión 5.

```
public void LogSistema(string Cadena, string Tipo)
    {
        try
        {
            string Log = Configuration.GetConnectionString("NombreLog");
            string LogSistematxt = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"\" + Log + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log";
           
            if (!File.Exists(LogSistematxt))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(LogSistematxt))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Tipo + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":" + Cadena);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(LogSistematxt))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Tipo + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":" + Cadena);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```